Calling an entry point inside an executable page allocated inside the kernel of an Android device (AOSP)
I am writing a kernel driver for Android (Pixel 8, Shiba, v5.15.148-android14-11, from AOSP, Android Open Source Project), which is running with AARCH64 architecture.
At the __init function, I am allocating (using valloc*() a few pages of kernel memory, giving them executable permissions (using set_memory_x(), which I get using kallsyms_lookup_name() which I get using the kprobe trick).
Similarly, I retrive set_memory_nx() and set_memory_ro().
Afterwards, I prepare the allocated pages for execution by inserting valid machine code, alligned to 4 bytes, and then call to the entry point of the code.
It immidiatly crashes the system as I call (or jump) the code.
Things I have checked:

There is no problem with the code itself, even an encoded ret instruction within the entry point crashes the system.
There is no problem with the call instruction, as even when I used a jump (br instead of blr instruction), it crashes immediately.
Whenever I do all the above within the __init function, it works like a charm. But whenever it is done through sysfs callback the system crashes.

On another note, additional issue that I've had, was related to the following:
I've tried to make the page executable and not writeable (as it may be that the kernel uses some sort of W^X feature that I am unaware of, but whenever I've tried to use set_memory_ro() not in the __init function but in a callback function I've registered through sysfs, the device immidiatly crashes as I called set_memory_ro() (or any other symbol I retreived using kallsyms_lookup_name() on that matter).
Similarly, whenever I've called set_memory_nx() in the __exit function of the kernel module, again, the system crashes.
But, whenever I use those functions within the __init function of the kernel module, they work as expected.
Any help, ideas or hints would be appriciated.

What do you mean by "crushes" the system? Instead of repeatedly using just a one word summation, describe the symptoms, i.e. what you actually see happen.

Thanks! I mean that the actual Pixel 8 device restarts immidiatly after I call/jump (blr and br instructions respectively) to the entry point I defined.

Seems like you do not have a system console which would display/report an exception or kernel panic.

Do you follow the ABI of your calls? Do you properly manage virtual and physical address spaces in your code?

Yes I follow the abi. I use the set_memory_x kernel symbol for permission setting, and I allocate only via valloc

From your comment it's unclear if you understood my question...

So can you please elaborate?
